# Modify labels in linguex

Tags: numbering, linguistics, linguex

I'm using the `linguex` package for writing examples. Now, I'd like to modify the labels in some cases to yield a', a'' for example. So, a MWE would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\begin{document}
\ex.\a. Example a
    \b. Example a'
    \c. Example b
\end{document}
```

The [docu](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/linguex/linguex-doc.pdf) didn't help unfortunately. Do you people have an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can supply a manual label to any example. Remember though that you can no longer refer to an example with such a label with the regular `\label` and `\ref` system, since the label is not a counter.  Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\begin{document}
\ex.
\a. First example.
\b.[a.$'$] Modified example.
\c.[a.$''$] Modified again.


\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Ah ok, cool. But would there be a workaround to also be able to reference to the labels?

Comment: Unfortunately the way `linguex` automatically formats `\ref{}` commands makes this difficult. In principle you should be able to build the reference by using `(\ref{foo}a$'$)` where 'foo` is the label inserted right after `\ex.`. But `linguex` preformats the `\ref{foo}` so that it comes out automatically as "(<num>)" which means that out of the box you can't do this.

Comment: For completeness sake. I found a workaround by doing `\Next` or `\Last` with the label name in brackets, so for instance `\Last[a.$'$]` produces the right reference to the example for me.